# Git - naming conventions in .config?

Tags: git, naming-conventions, git-config

I searched, but could not find if there is agreed naming convention for git configuration options and alike?

For example, opening typical git `.config` file, you can see options like `repositoryformatversion` or `logallrefupdates`. Those are not camelCase nor snake case. 
Is it recommended to use such convention (as seen by default options) when adding your custom config options?

Comment: There is no agreed convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [phd said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60527222/git-naming-conventions-in-config#comment107079712_60527222), there is no standard here.  Note that when Git looks things up internally, it just converts everything to lowercase, using the C language `tolower` function, and then compares the results.